# How to invite friends on wordpress without being logged in to the system

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

So I downloaded this great addon for wordpress called Invite Friends to Register - [Link](https://wordpress.org/plugins/invite-friends-to-register/)
And I wanted to tweak the code so that anyone who sees this page can invite their friends.
Can anyone help please? Much appreciated! 
Here is the code

Thanks!

```
/**
 * returns the javascript and form code for an ajax invite form
 */
function invfr_form() {
global $post, $invfr_add_scripts;

$invfr_add_scripts = true;

// only allow the form to be used if the user is logged in. 
// Offer a login link that redirects back to the page the form 
// was trying to be called on
if ( !is_user_logged_in() )
    $output = sprintf( __( 'You must be logged in to invite friends. <a href="%s">Log in</a>', 'invfr'), wp_login_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ) );
else {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_id = $user->ID;
    $user_name = $user->user_firstname ? $user->user_firstname : $user->user_nicename;
    $user_email = $user->user_email;
    ob_start(); ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(window).load(function(){ 
            jQuery('#invfr_form').submit(function() {
                // change visual indicators
                jQuery('td').removeClass('error');
                jQuery('.loading').show();
                jQuery('.submit input').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                // validate and process form here
                var str = jQuery(this).serialize();                  
                   jQuery.ajax({
                       type: 'POST',
                       url: '<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>',
                       data: str,
                       success: function(msg) { 
                            jQuery('#invfr_note').ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
                                msg = msg.replace(/(\s+)?.$/, "");  
                                if( msg == 'sent' ) {
                                    result = '<div class="updated"><p><?php _e( 'Your invitation has been sent! Send another?', 'invfr' ); ?></p></div>';
                                    jQuery('#invfr_form input[type=text], #invfr_form input[type=email]').val('');
                                } else {
                                    //loop through the error items to indicate which fields have errors
                                    msg = msg.replace(/[\[\]']+/g,'');
                                    msg = msg.split(',');
                                    jQuery.each( msg, function ( i, id ) {
                                        id = id.replace(/["']{1}/g, '');
                                        jQuery(id).parent('td').addClass('error');
                                    });
                                    result = '<div class="error"><p><?php _e( '<strong>ERROR:</strong> Check your form for the errors which are highlighted below.', 'invfr' ); ?></p></div>';
                                    //result = msg;
                                    msg = '';
                                }
                                jQuery(this).html(result);
                                // visual indicators
                                jQuery('.loading').hide();
                                jQuery('.submit input').removeAttr('disabled');                      
                            });                  
                        }                    
                    });                  
                return false;
            });         
        });
    </script>

    <div id="invfr_form_container">
        <p><?php echo sprintf( __( 'Enter your friend&rsquo;s name and email address to send them an invitation to register at %s', 'invfr' ), get_option( 'blogname' ) ); ?>
        <div id="invfr_note"></div>
        <form id="invfr_form" action="">
            <table class="form-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php _e( 'Friend&rsquo;s Name', 'invfr' ); ?></th>
                        <th><?php _e( 'Friend&rsquo;s Email', 'invfr' ); ?></th>
                        <th><a class="invfr_add button" href="#">+</a></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top"><label for="friend_name-0" class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Friend&rsquo;s Name', 'invfr' ); ?></label>
                        <input type="text" name="friend_name[0]" id="friend_name-0" value="" />
                        <span class="error-msg"><?php _e( 'Enter your friend&rsquo;s name', 'invfr' ); ?></span>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top"><label for="friend_email-0" class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Friend&rsquo;s Email', 'invfr' ); ?></label>
                        <input type="email" name="friend_email[0]" id="friend_email-0" value="" />
                        <span class="error-msg"><?php _e( 'Enter a valid email address', 'invfr' ); ?></span>
                    </td>
                    <td><a class="invfr_remove button" href="#">-</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <p class="submit"><input type="submit" value="<?php _e( 'Send Invitation', 'invfr' ); ?>" class="button button-primary" /> 
                <img src="<?php echo get_option( 'siteurl'); ?>/wp-admin/images/loading.gif" class="loading" /></p>

            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" value="<?php echo $user_id; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="user_name" value="<?php echo $user_name; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="user_email" value="<?php echo $user_email; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="invfr_process_ajax"/>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    $output = ob_get_contents();
    ob_clean();
}

return $output;
}

// Template tag
if ( !function_exists( 'invite_friends' ) ) {
function invite_friends( ) {
    echo invfr_form();
  }
  }  
// Shortcode
add_shortcode( 'invite_friends', 'invfr_form' );
/**
* callback for the users page that allows you to invite friends from the admin
*/
function invfr_invite_friends_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
    <?php screen_icon(); ?>
    <h2><?php _e( 'Invite Friends', 'invfr' ); ?></h2>
    <?php settings_errors(); ?>

    <?php echo invfr_form(); ?>
</div>
<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it might be as easy as just removing the conditional statement that checks if the user is logged in:

`if ( !is_user_logged_in() )
    $output = sprintf( __( 'You must be logged in to invite friends. <a href="%s">Log in</a>', 'invfr'), wp_login_url( get_permalink( $post->ID ) ) );
else {`

and the closing `}` wherever it is